# Laravel 8 no encuentra vista ERROR 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

El problema que tengo es que al acceder a otra vista desde un botón aparece error 404.

Según la documentación de *laravel 8* creo haber definido todo bien, además he implementado otras vistas así.

Dejo la ruta, el método del controlador y las vistas.

Ruta

```
Route::get('/seeds/import', 'App\Http\Controllers\web\v1\SeedController@import')->name('seeds.import');
```

Controlador (método)

```
public function import()
{
    return view('seeds.import');
}
```

Vista desde donde está el botón

```html
<div class="">
    <a class="btn btn-gradient-01 mr-1 mb-2" href="{{ route('seeds.create') }}">Crear nuevo semilla</a>
    <a class="btn btn-gradient-03 mr-1 mb-2" href="{{ route('seeds.import') }}">Importar base de datos</a>
</div>
```

La vista `import` es un *template* (no creo que tenga relevancia) y su *path* es `views\seeds\import.blade.php`

SOLUCIÓN:
El orden en que se definen las rutas es la solución al problema, este problema lo resolví en su momento y no lo compartí por acá. Ya no trabajo con Laravel pero si alguien le sirve aquí está: Si tienen definidas las rutas resource cambien el orden en que la definen, ejemplo si la definen antes de la ruta que comparte por ejemplo en mi caso seeds/import comparte las rutas con seeds/. Definan primero seeds/import y luego las rutas resource.

Comment: La ruta aparece en el listado con el comando artisan `route:list`?

Comment: si, | GET|HEAD | seeds/import  | seeds.import | App\Http\Controllers\web\v1\SeedController@import

Comment: A mi me está pasando lo mismo ahora y no sé porqué.. No es por crearla mal porque he creado vistas hasta ayer y funcionaban siempre.. no sé cual será el problema.. Repaso y repaso por si se me pasó algún fallo tonto pero de momento nada :-(

Answer (score 0):

En laravel 8 hubieron algunos cambios con las rutas web, en versiones anteriores podias sin problemas crear de esta forma las rutas (como tu lo tienes)

```
Route::get('/seeds/import', 'App\Http\Controllers\web\v1\SeedController@import')->name('seeds.import');
```

Ahora una opcion para crear rutas es de esta forma como lo recomiendan en la documentación de laravel https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;


Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Recuerda importar tu controlador, tambien puedes agregare el name

```
Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('ruta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuve ese problema y la verdad no tengo idea del por qué falla, cuando quise implementar un método que no existia me marcaba el 404 y si aparecia en la lista de rutas, probando soluciones desesperadas, cambié la ruta en el navegador y funcionó, supongo que por el resource causa algún conflicto. Por si no lo notan la ruta es products (en inglés) y lo cambié a español (productos) y así funcionó.

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
//Route::get('products/createBolsas', 'ProductController@createBolsas')->name('products.createBolsas');
Route::get('productos/createBolsas', 'ProductController@createBolsas')->name('products.createBolsas');
```